# How to make RefCell's Ref live long enough

Tags: reference, rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'm working on an interpreter in Rust for a programming language. Everything was going fine until I decided to implement closures, which caused some massive headaches because now each closure value needs to have a mutable reference of the environment it was defined in. I finally got it to mostly work with `RefCell`, but I'm now running into one more error that I can't figure out how to solve.

```
error: `e` does not live long enough
   --> src/interpreter.rs:163:23
    |
163 |             let val = e.lookup(&name);
    |                       ^ does not live long enough
...
169 |         }
    |         - borrowed value only lives until here
    |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'b as defined on the body at 147:93...
   --> src/interpreter.rs:147:94
    |
147 | fn eval_expr<'a, 'b, 'c>(ast: &'a Expr, env: &'b RefEnv<'b>) -> Result<Value<'b>, Error<'c>> {
    |                                                                                              ^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cell::RefCell;
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Value<'a> {
    Number(f64),
    UserFunc(Definition, Enviroment<'a>),
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Definition;

pub enum Expr {
    Name(String),
}

// Nothing to do with the problem
pub enum Error {
    UndefinedName(String),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Enviroment<'a> {
    current_frame: HashMap<String, Option<Value<'a>>>,
    prev: Option<&'a Enviroment<'a>>,
}
impl<'a> Enviroment<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Enviroment<'a> {
        Enviroment {
            current_frame: HashMap::new(),
            prev: None,
        }
    }
    pub fn extend(bindings: Vec<(String, Value<'a>)>,
                  prev: Option<&'a Enviroment<'a>>)
                  -> Enviroment<'a> {
        let mut frame = HashMap::new();
        for (key, val) in bindings {
            frame.insert(key, Some(val));
        }
        Enviroment {
            current_frame: frame,
            prev: prev,
        }
    }
    pub fn lookup(&self, name: &str) -> Option<Option<Value>> {
        let val = self.current_frame.get(&String::from(name));
        if val.is_some() {
            val.cloned()
        } else {
            if let Some(prev) = self.prev {
                prev.lookup(name)
            } else {
                None
            }
        }
    }
}

type RefEnv<'a> = RefCell<Enviroment<'a>>;

fn eval_expr<'a, 'b>(ast: &'a Expr, env: &'b RefEnv<'b>) -> Result<Value<'b>, Error> {
    match *ast {
        Expr::Name(ref name) => {
            let e = env.borrow();
            let val = e.lookup(&name);
            if let Some(Some(v)) = val {
                Ok(v)
            } else {
                Err(Error::UndefinedName(format!("{} is not defined", name)))
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

How can I change the code to make it compile?

Comment: Is cloning `v` an option? And do you understand what the issue would be if `v` was returned?

Comment: I tried inserting some clone calls (`let val = e.lookup(&name).clone();` and `Ok(v.clone())`, but I still get the error.

Comment: I know that returning `v` right now would be an error because the `Ref<Enviroment>` that it points to would be freed before it does.

Comment: Superb. Not quite sure about the issue yet, notably because of the lifetime dance with the environments...

Comment: Exactly. The closures need to have a reference to the environment the created them so that lexical scoping can work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really a problem regarding `RefCell` or `Ref`. You have this method:

```
impl<'a> Enviroment<'a> {
    pub fn lookup(&self, name: &str) -> Option<Option<Value>>;
}
```

After [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision) is reversed, that is equivalent to:

```
impl<'a> Enviroment<'a> {
    pub fn lookup<'b, 'c>(&'b self, name: &'c str) -> Option<Option<Value<'b>>>;
}
```

Which means that the `Value` is only guaranteed to contain values that live as long as the `Environment`. What you really want is to tie the `Value` to whatever the `Environment` references:

```
impl<'a> Enviroment<'a> {
    pub fn lookup(&self, name: &str) -> Option<Option<Value<'a>>>;
}
```

This allows your example code to compile.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I never would have guessed that that was the problem.